# problema para usar el scayt de ckeditor sin internet

Tags: php, ckeditor

Buenas tardes tengo configurado un `Scayt` en mi `CKEDITOR` y solo me funciona cuando tengo conectada la laptop a internet. Cuando no esta conectada me indica que ha fallado el `<script>` con origen en `http://svc.webspellchecker.net/spellcheck31/wscbundle/wscbundle.js` y no me realiza la comprobación ortográfica, existe alguna forma de hacer que `wcbundle.js` funcione sin necesidad de conectarme a internet, accedí al link antes mencionado y guarde su contenido en un `js` pero me sigue sin funcionar. Me puede dar alguna idea de como hacer que se active la corrección ortográfica sin necesidad de usar internet

Comment: Parece que la conexión es obligatoria, porque se requiere de un servidor para comprobar la ortografía, Referencia: https://docs.webspellchecker.net/display/WebSpellCheckerServer55x

Comment: @Triby pero tambien podría instalar el servidor en su propia maquina y así podría ejecutarlo offline

Comment: @braver, efectivamente, el enlace proporcionado es por si quiere instalarlo.

Comment: Existen dos versiones del servicio, uno basado en la nube (que requiere conexion obviamente) y otro de servidor/standalone que se puede instalar localmente. De todas maneras necesitas un servidor local para este caso para alojar el servicio, e incluso puede igual requerir acceso a internet por licencias o si cunsulta a un servicio externo